# python reshape - getting different results when flattened

Tags: python, reshape

Shouldn't both commands below return the same result? But in the below case I am getting different results...what am i missing?

```
A trick when you want to flatten a matrix X of shape (a,b,c,d) to a matrix X_flatten of shape (b ∗∗ c ∗∗ d, a) is to use:


X_flatten = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T      
train_set_x_flatten = train_set_x_orig.reshape(train_set_x_orig.shape[1]*train_set_x_orig.shape[2]*train_set_x_orig.shape[3],train_set_x_orig.shape[0] )
```

Comment: Items are read row-wise from multidim arrays. Reshape and transpose don't commute with each other. See `X.T.reshape(...)` for comparison

Comment: still not clear. i thought that the first command would take X and reshape it to matrix which has a rows and b*c*d columns and then transpose it. While the second command would do the same..what am i missing here?

Comment: how could i change the second command so that the output is similar to the output of the first command?

Comment: If you want the behaviour of the first, use `train_set_x_orig.reshape(train_set_x_orig.shape[0],-1).T`. The difference I was talking about is this, for instance: `X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1).T` versus `X.reshape(-1,X.shape[0])`: both give you an array of shape `(N,X.shape[0])`, but the elements will be mangled in the latter case. The rule of thumb is that the order of the dimensions shouldn't change during reshaping: `(a,b,c,d)` can be reshaped to `(a*b*c,d)` but not `(b*c*d,a)`. If you want to swap indices, you need to first transpose, then reshape (typically).

Comment: please write your comments as answer and i will accept it

Comment: Thanks, but frankly this is too fundamental for me to get rep for it:) There's probably also an appropriate duplicate somewhere. I rather suggest that you delete your question; you can do this without any repercussions as long as there are no answers or downvotes on your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a matter of sintaxis. Parenthesis are missing

Try this:

```
train_set_x_flatten = train_set_x_orig.reshape((train_set_x_orig.shape[1]*train_set_x_orig.shape[2]
* train_set_x_orig.shape[3], train_set_x_orig.shape[0]))
```